# Mysql 5.6 Function error statement

Tags: mysql, function

I try to write mysql function. I have mysql 5.6, and I don`t know why every time i try do it:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION do_it (s INT) RETURNS INT 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE k INT;
    SET k= s + 2;
    RETURN k;
    END;
```

I get:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 */

I know it is basic mistake, but I don`t know how I can fix it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter that MySQL is using or it will stop processing the `CREATE` request after the first semi-colon.

Do this:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION do_it (s INT) RETURNS INT 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE k INT;
    SET k= s + 2;
    RETURN k;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```